# State value is empty after using setState method in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I don't have much experience with React, and I'm stuck. When I've tried to update my state in componentDidUpdate method, I had infinity-loop-error, so I've added shouldComponentUpdate method - error is gone, but my state value (currentIncome) is still empty.

```
export class Company extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
        transactions: [],
        currentIncome: ''
    }

}

componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(`https://xxxxxx/incomes/${this.props.company.id}`, {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({transactions: data.incomes}))
}



componentDidUpdate = () => {
    const transactionsToFloat = this.state.transactions.map(item => parseFloat(item.value));
    let result = transactionsToFloat.reduce((acc, num) => {
        return acc+num;
    }, 0);
    result = Math.round(result*100)/100;
    this.setState({currentIncome: result});
}


shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    return this.state.currentIncome !== nextState.currentIncome
}


render(){
    console.log(this.state.currentIncome);
return(
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> {this.props.company.id}</th>
            <th> {this.props.company.name}</th>
            <th> {this.props.company.city}</th>
            <th> {this.state.currentIncome} </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
)
}
```

}

Comment: You have to calculate the currentIncome in `componentDidMount` after fetching the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `setState` unconditionally inside `componentDidUpdate`, it will cause an infinite loop of renders since `setState` leads to re-render and `componentDidUpdate` will be called after each render.

If I got the code right, you want to calculate `currentIncome` based on the fetch you did before. Then, you should calculate it right when you got the result from the fetch (after the Promise is solved).

So you should do something like that:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(`https://xxxxxx/incomes/${this.props.company.id}`, {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
                  let transactionsToFloat = data.incomes.map(item => parseFloat(item.value));
                  let result = transactionsToFloat.reduce((acc, num) => {
                         return acc+num;
                  }, 0);
                  result = Math.round(result*100)/100;
                  this.setState({transactions: data.incomes, currentIncome: result}
                  }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this out

Comment: Excellent! Happy coding :)

Comment: Never call `setState` **unconditionally** inside `componentDidUpdate`. You can call it, you just need to make sure it is inside a condition that will prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: @BrianThompson true.. that's more accurate. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `setState` in a condition in `componentDidUpdate` otherwise it will go in an infinite loop.

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or
>   you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra
>   re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the
>   component performance. If you’re trying to “mirror” some state to a
>   prop coming from above, consider using the prop directly instead. Read
>   more about why copying props into state causes bugs.

React Docs - [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)